# Php - add to Array fails, reference added

Tags: php, arrays, reference, addition

I have some wierd Problem with my php environment:

Code following:

```
public static function getAllVotesOfGroup($groupid){
    $con = new \SYSTEM\DB\Connection(new \DBD\uVote());
    $res = $con->prepare(   'selVoteByGrp',
                            'SELECT * FROM `uvote_votes` WHERE `group` = ?;',
                            array($groupid));
    $result = array();

    //$r = array();
    while($r = $res->next()){                        
        //print_r($r);                        
        $result[] = $r;
        print_r($result);            
        echo "</br></br>";
    }           
    //print_r($result);
    return $result;
}


public function next($object = false, $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH){        
    if($object){
        $this->current = mysqli_fetch_object($this->res);
    } else {
        $this->current = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->res);
    }
    return $this->current;
}
```

While on my other machine this code returns all the values i want this machine returns this: -> echo code from getAllVotesOfGroup(1)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [group] => 1 [title] => Test [text] => Testabstimmung [time_start] => 2013-06-12 [time_end] => 2015-06-13 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [group] => 1 [title] => Test2 [text] => Testabstimmung [time_start] => 2014-06-13 [time_end] => 2012-06-16 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [group] => 1 [title] => Test2 [text] => Testabstimmung [time_start] => 2014-06-13 [time_end] => 2012-06-16 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [group] => 1 [title] => Test3 [text] => bla [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [group] => 1 [title] => Test3 [text] => bla [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [group] => 1 [title] => Test3 [text] => bla [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [group] => 1 [title] => Test4 [text] => blub [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [group] => 1 [title] => Test4 [text] => blub [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [group] => 1 [title] => Test4 [text] => blub [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [group] => 1 [title] => Test4 [text] => blub [time_start] => 0000-00-00 [time_end] => 0000-00-00 ) )
```

As you can see the previous values are replaced, problably because $r is a reference and only the reference is added to the array not the actual values.

Why is that? Can i set some php.ini option to change that behaviour?

Addition:
This works fine! But is not what i want ;-)

```
    $result = array();

    while($r = $res->next()){                        
        $result[] = array('title' => $r['title'],'text' => $r['text']);
    }           
    return $result;
```

Ok I could solve it ;-)

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#83284

Problem is the mysqli-stmt-fetch im using which will return a reference not data.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as good as it should be as far as I can see (unless i'm missing something).

$result[] = $r;

This line is adding the new row to the array and not writing over the old value. To be honest I would be questioning what the other server returns for you.

Comment: Sorry Peter but you didnt get what i said, the problem is/was that the array was filled with the same values over and over again. That was because $res->next() returns a reference due to mysqli-prepare. Thanks  anyway ;-)

Comment: Ahh sorry you are quite right I missed that. Which version of php is on each of the 2 machines

Comment: both is php 5.3.3 -> by now im not sure it actually is a configuration problem either than a porting error from mysql->mysqli ;-)